# Order a "last action" column issue

Tags: laravel, datatable, eloquent

I've created a laravel application where we have users and every user have on other table x entries as "operation". In my backend I show all users with a datatable:

```
$users = User::all();
```

and I add a column "last action" that show the last record of the user added on the "operation" table:

```
    ->addColumn('last_action', function ($user) {

        $lastaction = Operations::where('user', $user->id)->orderBy('last_action','desc')->first();

        if (is_null($lastaction)) {
            return '<span class="label label-warning">nothing</span>';
        } else {
            $carbonated_date = Carbon::parse($lastaction->last_action);
            return '<span class="label label-success">'.$carbonated_date->diffForHumans().'</span>';
        }
    })
```

The problem is that if I try to order "last action" column I've wrong order like this:

- Name Last Action
- Bob  nothing
- Mark 2 Days ago
- Roger nothing
- Alex    nothing
- Tom 3 Days    ago

...

What wrong here?

Comment: What is the problem here? I'm sure your order by works fine, maybe you wanted your list of users sorted by `last_action`? You do that by `$users = User::orderBy('last_action','desc')->get();`

Comment: You need to use a specific datetime format in order to allow DataTable to order your data. Usually, it's a format natively supported by JavaScript (YYYY, MM, DD).

Comment: Last action is on another table stored as datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Best and correct way is to make several steps:

1. in `Opration.php` add following method:

```html
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'last_action',
];
```

2. in the same model you can create scope function:

```html
/**
 * Order users by last action.
 * 
 * @param $query
 * @return mixed
 */
public function scopeByLastAction($query)
{
    return $query->orderBy('last_action', 'desc');
}
```

3. and then you can simply use it `User::operations()->byLastAction()->get();`

This is correct way, but you need to make sure that you have relationship function in `User` model.

Comment: I take last action from another table that store user operations.

Comment: uhm ok, I'll try now your solution.

Comment: User model must have an HasMany relationship?

Comment: Yep. hasMany & belongTo